# npm install stucks in the terminal

Tags: angular, npm, terminal, install.packages

I have cloned an angular project and used `npm install --force` to install the packages but it stucks in the terminal as shown in the pic

[image: terminal screen shot]

and here are my env versions

> node: v18.12.1

> npm: 8.19.2

and here are the dependecies in the project

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^14.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@mirei/leaflet-semicircle-ts": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/leaflet.fullscreen": "^1.6.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "http-server-pwa": "^2.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.8.0",
    "leaflet.fullscreen": "^2.4.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Comment: Sometimes, one or two steps take lot of times. Also, maybe you can use CTRL+C to leave if it never finish

Comment: @Elikill58 It have taken about 45 mins and not finished yet

Comment: Is your disk ok? Can you run it with the `-v` flag to see if it's doing something? Are you running this in some VM?

Comment: @Evert No, I'm not running it on any VM, my machine has only ubuntu 22 OS

Comment: You answered 1/3rd of my questions

Comment: @Evert 
1- Yes my disk is Ok
2- I don't know what the `flag -v` does, It suppose to show the version ??
When I use the flag -v it return the version of npm and the version of npm I have already mentioned above

Comment: Anyway, I have terminated the process using `CTRL + C` after long time and it worked well, but when I terminated the proecess after short time, it didn't work.
I really don't know the reason for that